# Valet: 502 bad gateway when running test.dev on a mac, laravel, php install

Tags: php, macos, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I installed locally php71 with fpm on a mac.
Then got valet working when going to 'ping anyting.dev'.

Then went into directory 'PHP_Apps' where I have all my php apps installed and ran 'valet park' in that directory. Inside it I created a 'test' directory containing an index.php file.
Going in the browser to index.dev displays:

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.2

Also the log file records:

> 2017/01/31 16:58:48 [crit] 285#0: *16 connect() to
>   unix:/Users/ME/.valet/valet.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request:
>   "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/Users/ME/.valet/valet.sock:", host: "test.dev",
>   referrer: "http://test.dev/"

Does the same when pointing to laravel install dirs.

I'm unfamiliar with nginx. What is the file it doesn't find exactly ?
And how to resolve this problem ?

EDIT: I don't have a valet.sock file, that might be the problem but I don't know what to put inside.

Answer (score 11):

Try to run `valet install` again, it might have something wrong with the configuration.